# How can I format a number as letters in RTF template using BI Publisher Desktop?

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

How can I format a number as spelled out words in RTF template?

For example 31 to read Thirty One, 125 hundred twenty five and so forth.

Thanks,
Zee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIP provides a function for this called xdofx:to_check_number.
It is documented over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e13881/T527073T558233.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about this method so I format it in my query using this SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (234, 'j'), 'jsp') FROM DUAL;
//Output: two hundred thirty-four.  But what I liked the most about formatting in the RTF itself is the different ways of format.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a check, the out-of-the-box check printing process includes the text in the outbound payment XML. Should be easy to find the element that includes it.